# Preview Doc, Xls, PPT, MHT, TIFF, DWG files in my web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to preview  Doc, Xls, PPT, MHT, TIFF, DWG files in my web browser (same as pdf files open in browser using acrobat reader).

I has searched a lot on google, but not got any help. If anyone can suggest me how can I start this, it will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Richa Sharma

Comment: You would need a system, service, or library that can convert those file formats into something that most browsers can display.

Comment: The commercial Aspose library seems to cover your scenario, though it is expensive.